# Mind transfer ability for planetary travel by some people a few times

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to help my wife find the name of a book, possibly a book series.  In this series, some people have the ability to transfer their consciousness into people on other planets that are too far apart for space travel to be practical.  The two main characters are spies that fall in love and marry and have a descendant or daughter (possibly named Melody).

The folks that can do the transfer can only transfer a few times (up to 5 with 5 being very rare) because they then lose their sense of self.

She says that one of the worlds was a world of intelligent fish.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is it Piers Anthony day or something?  This sounds a lot like the [*Cluster* series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_(novels)).

In the first novel [*Cluster*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?5288) the protagonist, Flint is recruited by Sol Sphere to contact other nearby spheres using Kirlian mind transfer to enlist them in a struggle to save the galaxy from the evil Andromedans.  He is chased by a female Andromedan agent, and naturally they fall in love.

The second book [*Chaining the Lady*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?5289) has their daughter Melody as the protagonist.

Comment: Outstanding, thanks tons!  

Piers Anthony Day?  Sounds awesome!  ;^)  :-)