Sci-fi book with a male protagonist whose consciousness is transferred into other bodies (including an amoeba/jellyfish creature) after he is killed
Trying to find the title of a sci-fi book I read in middle school.
Male protagonist. He originally has a muscular green body, but is killed/crushed. His consciousness is somehow transported elsewhere, where he inhabits other bodies. In one of these adventures, he becomes an amoeba/jellyfish type creature. New to this body/culture, he doesn't understand things and eventually engages in nonconsensual sex with two other organisms.
It read like it was possibly pre-90s work, likely 60s/70s.

In which years were you in middle school?

OP here: I read this book in 1990, most likely.

Sounds like the protagonist was an alien to begin with? And his consciousness was transferred into other alien species on different planets? Is that right?

Is it possible that the muscular green body was one of the bodies he inhabited rather than his original? Does this ring any bells: he was human and transported to another/far future world where he can move into various bodies - from squid-like creatures to snow beasts to crystalline flying humanoids. And has sex with them all, pretty much.

If so, yes, I know what that book is.

This is Piers Anthony's Cluster series, the first book of which is Cluster from 1977. From the Wikipedia description:

Sphere Sol's highest-Kirlian individual at the time is Flint, a green-skinned native of Outworld, Sphere Sol's most distant planet.

His mind/soul is shifted to host bodies of various other alien species by a process called "transfer" and he has alien sex while in most of the different bodies.
At the end

Choosing to leave things as they are, with parity between their two galaxies, Flint and the Andromedan mate and remain together until their auras fade (which happens rapidly since their physical bodies have been destroyed).

The "amoeba like" aliens are Spicans, a species with three genders. When representatives of all three are together, they will have sex. Flint triggers this situation accidentally once and then exploits it a few times afterwards, essentially raping the others involved.

Duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263982/mind-transfer-ability-for-planetary-travel-by-some-people-a-few-times/ and probably others.
